# How to bulk upload raster datasets to ArcGIS Online as separate discrete layers?

Tags: raster, arcgis-online, web-service

I have 18 raster datasets which I need to publish through ArcGIS online to allow users to turn on/off each layer and toggle transparency. I have the data stored in a file gdb as below:

[image]

I am looking at ways of doing this more efficiently than publishing 18 separate services for each layer. The service will be shared to ArcGIS Server Manager.

Can anybody help?

Comment: do you plan on caching the imagery or publishing it as a dynamic service?

Comment: Caching only, yet I need to be able to toggle between layers

Comment: I guess the only other question I have (before I respond) is if you have ArcGIS for Server to store your imagery? Or are you using ArcGIS Online to act as your storage space (this will use credits and cost a pretty penny)

Comment: @MDHald yes, ArcGIS Server (thankfully)

Comment: "Discreet layers" are usually sold by outfits like [Victoria's Secret](https://www.victoriassecret.com/).  Although you probably intended "discrete," it's unclear what distinction this adds to "separate."

Comment: Oh dear, silly me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Add all your imagery to one Map Document. ( I have used Mosaic Datasets in this image -  but there will be no difference in how your imagery acts in this process)

[image]

2. Share your Map Document to your Server via File>Share As>Service.

[image]

3. Setup all the requirements in terms of name, location, settings and cache.[image] - Wait for the cache to complete and then navigate to your server web address. (e.g. http://[yournamehere]/arcgis/rest/services)
4. Navigate to your Services section and click the link to the imagery service you published (the name you established in the Service Editor.

[image]

5. Click the name of the image you would like to add as a 'separate' layer to ArcGIS Online.

[image]

6. After you have clicked through your webpage should look like the one below

[image]

7. go to the top of the page and capture the URL. This will give you a direct link which you can add in ArcGIS Online.

[image]

8. copy this link and head over to ArcGIS Online. Click Map>Add>Add Layer From Web. 
   [image]

   9. paste your link (e.g. http://[yournamehere]/arcgis/rest/services/[servicename]/MapServer/[serviceid]) into the Add Layer From Web Window

[image]

10. click add. Repeat steps 5 - 9 for each image you would like to control transparency and toggle.

Answer (score 1):

Script it with ArcPy! You can create a script which loops through the gdb and publishes each raster it finds.

Here is an example of a *update feature service on AGOL script* which you can edit for your needs.
https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/04/23/updating-arcgis-com-hosted-feature-services-with-python/

You can find more information over here:
https://geonet.esri.com/message/316359#316359

Comment: This is an automated way of publishing 18 separate services. Is there no way of uploading the raster datasets as separate layers in one service, as with vector files?

Comment: It depends on what your goal is. You can indeed automatically publish them in one mxd-file and you can call them seperately, but is it enough?

Comment: How can I call them separately though from one mxd?

Comment: You can call them seperatly with the rest-url. Take a look at the following url: http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Fire/Sheep/MapServer. You'll see that this service contains 3 layers. When you publish all the rasters in 1 webmap the interface will look the same.